# Save additional user data on registration in Firebase using React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword but I also wanted to save additional data such as the first name and last name in the registration screen.

I have tried doing this code but it only creates the user with the email and password. It does not save the first name and last name of the user in the database.

```
signUpUser = (email, password, firstName, lastName) => {
    try {
      if (this.state.password.length < 6) {
        alert("Please enter atleast 6 characters");
        return;
      }
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(
        firebase.database().ref('users.' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/').set({
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName
        })
      )

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you're passing the result of the `set()` function to `then()`?  `then()` normally takes a function argument for a callback.  `set()` returns a promise, which you should instead check for error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const addProfile = ({firstname, lastname, email}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  var d = new Date();
  var userId = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid;

  var userProfile = {
    created: d,
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
  };

  firebaseApp.database().ref(`profiles/${userId}`).set(userProfile)
  .then( () => resolve(userProfile) )
  .catch( error => reject(error) );

});
```